# How do I get the value of a textbox after it changes in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to get the value of a textbox after it changes. Textboxes are blank, and when the user makes an input, it automatically multiplies to the value set. What I want is to get the computed value so that I can add all the value of each textboxes. I hope you can help me with this one.

Edit: I created this for testing. It's not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<input id="first" type="text" onchange="compute()">

<script>
$('#first').on('change', function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val() * 3);
});
</script>

<input id="second" type="text" onchange="compute()">

<script>
$('#second').on('change', function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val() * 3);
});
</script>


<input id="result" type="text" readonly>

<script>
        function compute(){
                var myBox1 = document.getElementById('first').value;
                var myBox2 = document.getElementById('second').value;
                var result = document.getElemetById('result').value;
                var grade = first + second;
                result.value = grade;
        }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your HTML? What have you tried? What went wrong? Where did you get stuck? What problem, exactly, are you trying to solve?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mix attribute based events with jquery. You do not need them. jQuery allows multiple handlers per element and also keeps the code together (better than having an attribute buried elsewhere in the HTML).

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/8o2z0agw/1/

```
$('#first').on('change', function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val() * 3);
    compute();
});

$('#second').on('change', function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val() * 3);
    compute();
});

function compute() {
    var first = ~~$('#first').val();
    var second = ~~$('#second').val();
    var result = $('#result');
    var grade = first + second;
    result.val(grade);
}
```

You also wanted to use jQuery selectors in preference to getElementById and use .val() to get.set values.

Note: `~~` is a faster shortcut for converting values to ints (instead of `parsetInt`).

As the code is indentical for the two change handlers, you can combine them into one:

```
$('#first,#second').on('change', function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val() * 3);
    compute();
});
```

If your jQuery code is included prior to the elements (which it sounds like it now is), you need to enclose it in a DOM ready handler to ensure the elements are found when the selector runs.

```
$(function(){
    $('#first,#second').on('change', function () {
        $(this).val($(this).val() * 3);
        compute();
    });
});
```

Note: `$(function(){});` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){});`

An alternative to DOM ready is a delegated event handler, attached to `document`, which does not require a DOM ready handler as the jQuery selector is run *at event time* and `document` always exists at any time during page load.

```
$(document).on('change', '#first,#second', function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val() * 3);
    compute();
});
```

This works by listening for an event (e.g. `change`( bubbling up to the target element (document in this case), *then* applying the jQuery selector to the chain of bubbling elements only, *then* applying the function to the matching elements *that caused the event*. This means a delegated event can work with elements that may exist "later".

Comment: Hey man. The fiddle works fine. But when I try to test it on me, nothing happens. I've saved the jquery file seperately and embedded it on my html file. Butttttttt nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the file is included before the elements in the page, it needs to be enclosed in a DOM ready handler... I will add an update.

Answer (score 2):

One very simple solution to achieve this with jquery is:

```js
$('#first, #second').on('change', function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val() * 3);
    if ($("#first").val() != "" && $("#second").val())
        $("#result").val(parseInt($("#first").val(), 10) + parseInt($("#second").val(), 10));
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="first" type="text" />
<input id="second" type="text" />
<input id="result" type="text" readonly="true" />
```

Answer (score 2):

My own take, while you've already accepted an answer, is:

```js
$('input[type=text]').on('change', function() {
  $(this).val(function(i, v) {
    return parseInt(v, 10) * 3;
  });
  compute();
});

function compute() {
  $('#result').val(function() {
    return $('input[type="text"]').not(this).map(function() {
      return parseInt(this.value, 10) || 0;
    }).get().reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="first" type="text" />

<input id="second" type="text" />
<input id="result" type="text" readonly>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
  - [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
- jQuery:

  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
  - [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you probably need to close your input tags `<input ... />`

This is one way you can achieve what you want using jQuery. One thing you should check if the value inputed is a valid number. Also, you need to take into account each input separately so the result stil gets calculated even if only one value is inputed.

```
$('#first').on('change', function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val() * 3);
    compute();
});

$('#second').on('change', function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val() * 3);
    compute();
});

function compute() {
    var first = parseInt($('#first').val());
    var second = parseInt($('#second').val());
    var result = 0;
    if(!isNaN(first)) {
        result += first;
    }
    if(!isNaN(second)) {
        result += second;   
    }
    if(result != 0) {
        $('#result').val(result);
    }
}
```

[**Here is a working fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/1h0prk8L/11/)

Comment: Closing inputs is a good practice, and it stops color-coded warnings in JSFiddles, but it not necessary on any browser.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, that is why I said "probably" :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#first').change(...)
```

change event will be called after the element is unfocused, so if you want to get the value of the element during typing, try

> $('#first').keyup(...)

here is a complete sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#tst").change(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
      });

      $("#tst").keyup(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
      });
  });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
 <input type="text" id="tst">
</body>

</html>
```